# Python sklearn: why are my neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor predictions "perfect"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, knn

I am running the following code:

```
from sklearn import neighbors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 1), columns=list('T'))
KNN_ = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=20, weights='distance').fit(X, y)
yhat = KNN_.predict(X)
error = yhat-y
print(error)
```

Why are all the errors zero? As I understand it, the error should capture the difference between the fitted/ predicted values and my data points?

I have applied essentially the same procedure with other estimators (such as Random Forest Regressor) and the error was nonzero as expected, so I fear I am missing a subtlety here in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are training and testing on the same dataset. You are using `X` for training in the following line

```
KNN_ = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=20, weights='distance').fit(X, y)
```

and then predicting on the same values

```
yhat = KNN_.predict(X)
```

You need to break your dataset into train and test, like tran_X and test_X. Then train on train_X and predict using test_X.

**Update** If you read the [documentation of KNN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html) it says that

> The target is predicted by local interpolation of the targets associated of the nearest neighbors in the training set.

So basically when you are supplying the new targets to predict, it locally interpolates the training set. Since, the values are exactly the same, it returns back the exact data row and label. My point here is, the difference in error has to do with how KNN actually works internally. My guess is, since RandomForest is a sort of ensemble of decision trees to prevent overfitting, there is scope of error being non-zero(that is the whole point of preventing overfitting). You need to take a look at how these algorithms work internally to get an idea about that. You can take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104255/why-would-anyone-use-knn-for-regression) and [this](http://www.saedsayad.com/k_nearest_neighbors_reg.htm) to get an idea about why the predictions are exactly the same.

Comment: I am aware it's the same data. But still, why would the predictions be *perfect*? There should still be some in-sample error?